# Is there any alternative mail template like velocity engine template

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Is there any alternative email template like velocity engine temple which is used in spring boot and can be used in the upcoming spring versions.since velocity engine template became deprecated in spring 4.3

Comment: This is off topic for Stack Overflow: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: freemarker and thmeleaf I think. [more](http://nixmash.com/java/the-move-from-velocity-to-freemarker-with-spring-boot/)

Comment: Have a look: http://www.javatpoint.com/spring-java-mail-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Spring supports various email templates like thymeleaf, freeMarker, Groovy, etc

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**Thymeleaf**](http://dolszewski.com/spring/sending-html-mail-with-spring-boot-and-thymeleaf/), Freemarker, Groovy templates

Check the sample implementations at spring-boot repositories ->

[FreeMarker](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-freemarker)

[Groovy Template](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-groovy-templates)